# Some cities refuse to georeference in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, geocoding

My dataset includes two columns, "City" and "Country." The cities are all major world cities, nothing obscure. All are georeferencing fine in CartoDB, *except* Rome, Italy, and Moscow, Russia. I've even tried georeferencing in a different account, starting from scratch with a fresh, manually created dataset. But those two cities just return null values and error messages. (I've also tried variations like Roma, Moscova, and Italia.)

Any idea what's going on here? Yes, I know I could type in a lat/long manually, but I'm really curious if there's a glitch here, or if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Seems an error in our part. We get city names from the Geonames database, but by some reason Rome and Moscow are not there. Reported here: https://github.com/CartoDB/data-services/issues/134

Comment: Thanks, @iriberri ! At first I read your comment to mean that Rome and Moscow aren't in the Geonames database, but I just checked and they ARE there, so I guess you're saying they got dropped somewhere between there and the CartoDB database. Thanks for the follow-up.

Comment: Yes, they're in geonames, but not in our production copy of it. I'll try to guess what happened asap :)

Comment: @iriberri. For what it is worth I have noticed lots of problems in Wales too. Fortunately, we have our own db, but it is the only part of CartoDB where I have noticed real problems.

Comment: If you have a list of cities that should appear and they aren't, don't hesitate to add them here. That would be useful in order to check if an update will solve the issue totally. :)

Answer (score 1):

This was due to a problem CartoDB had in the geocoder with some missing rows, that was fixed around three weeks ago. Now, cities as Rome or Moscow can be geocoded directly :-)